# Openswan tunnel to remote public NAT'd host

Tags: amazon-ec2, vpn, iptables, nat, openswan

Need help on this VPN set-up to work.
Left-hand.  EC2:

- eth0:10.0.0.100/EIP=1.1.1.1 (ie. NAT'd IP)
- eth1:10.0.0.200/EIP=2.2.2.2
- Peer ip/leftid: 1.1.1.1

Right-hand. Cisco:

- Peer ip: 3.3.3.3
- Peer host/rightsubnet: 3.3.3.30/32 (Public NAT'd ip)

Cisco ACL:
permit ip host 3.3.3.30/32 host 2.2.2.2 (LH eth1)

1. Tunnel is UP because outbound ping/telnet packets to 3.3.3.30 are going through the tunnel, but not replying/routing back.
2. Do I need to set up SNAT, DNAT, or masquerade in IPTABLES.

Basically the goal is for LH to reach Peer host using Public NAT'd IPs.

Any helpful tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Sharing my findings to solve my own issue, and could be for some.
The ipsec.conf param leftsourceip saved the day! :)
No iptables NAT required for my case at least.
Here's the fully working ipsec.conf
Hope this would be helpful to others who hit similar issue.

> conn myVPN
>
> > type=tunnel
> >         forceencaps=yes
> >         authby=secret
> >         ike=3des-sha1;modp1024
> >         keyexchange=ike
> >         ikelifetime=86400s
> >         phase2=esp
> >         phase2alg=3des-sha1
> >         salifetime=3600s
> >         pfs=no
> >         auto=start
> >         keyingtries=3
> >         rekey=no
> >         left=%defaultroute
> >         leftnexthop=%defaultroute
> >         leftid=1.1.1.1
> >         leftsourceip=2.2.2.2
> >         right=3.3.3.3
> >         rightid=3.3.3.3
> >         rightsubnet=3.3.3.30/32
> >         rightnexthop=%defaultroute

Answer (score 1):

Sharing your findings did help someone! :)

Fixed the exact issue I was facing!!

Thanks for posting the solution!!!

Here is what I needed to additionally do to forward packets to the other side:

- on the left side, enable forwarding

  echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
- allocate an EIP (1.1.1.1) and associate to eth0 interface on AWS instance
- add another EIP (2.2.2.2) and associate to eth1 interface on same instance
- set the leftsourceip (2.2.2.2) address as a sub interface eth1:1
- set eth0 as the default gateway

  Centos - add "GATEWAYDEV=eth0" to /etc/sysconfig/network
- turn source/destination checking to disabled on both instance interfaces in AWS console
- iptables SNAT rules to rewrite the source header of the packet so
  that anything coming in from a local AWS host on eth1 appears to come
  from the encryption domain (leftsource) on eth1. e.g. 10.0.0.123, an IP in the same collision domain inside the VPC that the VPN instance belongs to needs to go out and get to the destination. Also allow any existing established or related sessions to pass.

  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 10.0.0.123 -j SNAT --to-source 2.2.2.2

  iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

  iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT